# Crumble added to muffins before baking

Tags: muffins

I put a crumble on my blueberry as recipe called for, why did they caved in?  Could it be the altitude?

Comment: More info would be helpful here. A recipe, perhaps a picture, what is your altitude, and have you ever made them before? Welcome to Seasoned Advice, BTW.

Comment: The tops of your blueberry muffins have deflated--is that the problem?

Comment: yummmmmmyyyyyy!

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking if the crumble is the source of your problem - it isn't.

Without a recipe and some indication of how you mix and bake your muffins, it is difficult to determine the cause of your cave-ins.  This is a common problem with muffins and cupcakes, though.  The most likely culprits are:  (1) too much liquid in your batter, (2) oven not hot enough, (3) chemical leavener is spent or you used too little, (3) you use too *much* leavener, (4) you didn't bake them long enough, (5) you used too much batter for each muffin (filling the cups too full), & (6) overmixing.

If you are following a respected recipe carefully and you know your leavener is fresh, then please make sure you are cooking in an oven that has been pre-heated fully to the temperature in your recipe - that temperature probably shouldn't be below 375°F (and, of course, altitude could be an issue here - how high-up are you?).  Most importantly, mix your ingredients only long enough for them to just barely come together (remember that it's OK if little traces of unincorporated flour are still visible) - mix by hand if you have used an electric mixer in the past.  Finally, avoid filling the cups in your muffin tin more than 2/3 full - using more better doesn't always make larger muffins - at some point, the muffin loses its ability to support the doming of the center.